# How to plot a curve and error bars of the same color in holoviews with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, holoviews

I want to plot a curve with error bars in `holoviews` using the `matplotlib` backend. I would like the curve and the error bars to be the same color, but without explicitly specifying the color for the curve. I.e. I can easily do this

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("matplotlib")

means = [1, 4, 2, 3]
errors = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1]
color = "green"
mean_plot = hv.Curve(means).opts(color=color)
err_plot = hv.ErrorBars((range(len(means)), means, errors)).opts(edgecolor=color)
mean_plot * err_plot
```

to get

[image]

but what if I was given `mean_plot` and didn't already know its color? I'm sure the current options must be stored somewhere on the instance, but I don't know how to access them. I'd like to do something like

```py
mean_color = mean_plot.<access_options_somehow>.color
err_plot = hv.ErrorBars((range(len(means)), means, errors)).opts(edgecolor=mean_color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Sheldore's answer and my comment there, here's an approach that first renders the `holoviews` element to a `matplotlib` figure and then finds the color there. This isn't very elegant, and I think there must be a nicer way, but it gets the job done.

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("matplotlib")

means = [1, 4, 2, 3]
errors = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1]
color = "green"
mean_plot = hv.Curve(means).opts(color=color)

fig = hv.render(mean_plot)
ax = fig.axes[0]
line = ax.get_lines()[0]
mean_color = line.get_color()

err_plot = hv.ErrorBars((range(len(means)), means, errors)).opts(edgecolor=mean_color)
mean_plot * err_plot
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have `holoviews` installed but since it is using `matplotlib`, you can try the generic solution to extract the color of the line and then use it to plot the error bars

```
mean_plot = hv.Curve(means) # Don't specify any color here
mean_color = mean_plot[0].get_color() # Extract the default color
err_plot = hv.ErrorBars((range(len(means)), means, errors)).opts(edgecolor=mean_color)
```

Comment: This won't work with `holoviews`. Indexing into `mean_plot` gives the data used for the plot (so, in my example, `mean_plot[0]` is `1`). I haven't used it before, so I'd have to search the docs for how, but I believe there is a way to get the `matplotlib` figure from the `holoviews` element; it's possible that's the only way, though I'd prefer a `holoviews`-y solution if there is one.